# configuration file in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

**can any one make me understand meaning of this code or provide me reference to some site**

```
<global>
    <models>
        <test>**what does this <test>(line 3) indicate (name of module or just reference to below class file)**
            <class>Excellence_Test_Model</class> <!-- Location of all model class files -->
            <resourceModel>test_mysql4</resourceModel> <!-- Location of resource model -->
        </test>
        <test_mysql4>
            <class>Excellence_Test_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <test> 
                    <table>test_tablename</table>  <!-- Actual table name in sql  -->
                </test>
            </entities>
        </test_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>  <!-- These are resource setting giving access to module, read/write permission on database -->
        <test_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Excellence_Test</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </test_setup>
        <test_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </test_write>
        <test_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </test_read>
    </resources>
</global>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<test>` node beneath `<models>` defines how you go about referring to the model classes within the extension using a call to `Mage::getModel()`.  In your case you have set `test` so you would use a call like:

```
Mage::getModel('test/some_model')
```

to reference class `Excellence_Test_Model_Some_Model`.  Nothing else is flagged in the config you posted - what else do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento you can instantiate models using the `Mage::getModel()` factory like this:

```
Mage::getModel('something/other_thing');
```

The parameter you give to the factory contains one slash `/`.
What's before the slash represents the model group, what's behind it represents the rest of the class name.
In your case `test` represents the group name.
So if you have this in `config.xml`.

```
<models>
    <test>
        <class>Excellence_Test_Model</class>
    </test>
</models>
```

When calling `Mage::getModel('test/something_here')` magento will look for the class to load like this:

split the parameter by slash and end up with

```
array(
    'test', //model group identifier
    'something_here' //rest of the class name
)
```

Look in config for the node `models->test->class` and append to that value the rest of the class name but with uppercase first letter for everything that's separated by underscore.

So you end up with

```
test -> Excellence_Test_Model
something_here -> Something_Here
```

Concatenating these values by underscore you end up with the real class name: `Excellence_Test_Model_Something_Here`.

This class then gets autoloaded, but this is a different topic.